# Set both interpolated and message template on ConstraintValidatorContext

Tags: java, bean-validation

I am in need to call validator.validateProperty() from my custom Validator and looking for a way to pass BOTH messageTemplate and interpolated message to ConstraintValidatorContext.
What i want to achieve is that if given property has a particular value than fire validation of another property.

```
MyCustomClassLevelValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Foo, Bar>{
@Autowired
private Validator validator
 public boolean isValid(Bar bar,
        ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext){
    if(bar.isSth()){
      Set<ConstraintViolation<Bar>> somePropViolations = validator.validateProperty(bar, "someprop", Conditional.class);
      for (ConstraintViolation<Bar> propertyViolation : somePropViolations) {
         constraintValidatorContext.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
         constraintValidatorContext.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(propertyViolation.getMessageTemplate()).addNode(propertyViolation.getPropertyPath().toString())
            .addConstraintViolation();
   }   
    }
 }
}
```

So the problem with my code is that when Bar is validated, constraint violations on "someprop" are not fully interpolated (constraint annotations attributes are not resolved)

```
class Bar{
  ...
  @Digits(groups=Conditional.class, integer=4,fraction=0)
  String someProp;
}
```

So when validating Bar like

```
Bar bar = new Bar();
bar.setSomeProp("99.9");
Set<ConstraintViolation<Bar>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(bar);
```

i see numeric value out of bounds (<{integer} digits>.<{fraction} digits> expected)
instead of 
numeric value out of bounds (<4 digits>.<0 digits> expected)

Is there any way i put BOTH message Template and message text (interpolated version) on constraintValidatorContext ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a good idea to call back to `Validator` from within a constraint validator implementation, as this might easily cause endless loops when validating the same object again, which hosts the current object.

Depending on how you invoke validation, you could you simply pass the `Conditional` group to the validation call:

```
if(bar.isSth()) {
    Set<ConstraintViolation<Bar>> constraintViolations = 
        validator.validate(bar, Conditional.class);
}
else {
    Set<ConstraintViolation<Bar>> constraintViolations =
        validator.validate(bar);
}
```

Comment: Hi Gunnar this is what i finally ended up.